# Python, threads over riding each other when dumping to JSON files

Tags: python, json

I'm running multiple threads which each dump to the same JSON file however these dump around exactly the same time, this is causing issues with my JSON file were they override each other. I read the JSON file right before dumping however they're being read at the same time and over-riding each other does anyone have a solution for this?

Comment: Don't use threads? Don't dump to the same file?

Comment: Synchronize your threads.

Comment: In addition to @DanielRoseman, if you have to do those, `threading.Lock` the threads when writing.

Comment: Aren't threads kinda meant to be run at the same time? You could use mutexes to synchronize them, but that may make your code sequential again, which would defeat the purpose of having threads in the first place.

Comment: Why are you running multiple threads which dump to the same JSON file? Explain the root problem you're trying to solve. This sounds like an [XY problem](http://xyproblem.info/).

Comment: @ForceBru If the threads do some other heavy work and are only synchronized for the writing operation you'd still have most benefits of multithreading. I have no clue if that's the case for OP's program, of course.